# How can I escape a caret, tilde and curly braces in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to find special characters in SQL like [this tutorial](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/finding-special-characters-within-character-strings), but I'd like to expand the character set.

Say I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE SpecialCharacter (
    SampleString varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO SpecialCharacter (SampleString) VALUES ('   !"#$%&''()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~');
INSERT INTO SpecialCharacter (SampleString) VALUES (' !"#$%&''()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{}~');
INSERT INTO SpecialCharacter (SampleString) VALUES ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
INSERT INTO SpecialCharacter (SampleString) VALUES ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\u001a');
INSERT INTO SpecialCharacter (SampleString) VALUES ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzģ');
INSERT INTO SpecialCharacter (SampleString) VALUES ('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
INSERT INTO SpecialCharacter (SampleString) VALUES ('-');
INSERT INTO SpecialCharacter (SampleString) VALUES ('c-r');
INSERT INTO SpecialCharacter (SampleString) VALUES ('_noice');
INSERT INTO SpecialCharacter (SampleString) VALUES ('_noice^^');
```

And I have the below query:

```
select * from SpecialCharacter WHERE SampleString LIKE '%[^ !"#$\%&''()*+,-./0-9A-Za-z:;<=>@\[\\\]\_]%' ESCAPE '\' AND SampleString LIKE '%[^{}~]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

I've managed to figure out how to find all the characters except for `^`. The closest I got for `^` was something like the below:

```
select * from SpecialCharacter WHERE SampleString LIKE '%[\^]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

This works when I want to find data in `column` containing `^`. However, I'd like to find data in `column` that contains something that's not in the list of acceptable characters.

`~`, `{` and `}` on its own works, but does not work when I put it into the `LIKE` statement with everything else, which is why I separated them. But if I can put them in the same statement that'd be great, too.

What am I missing? I can't use `CONTAINS` or `FREETEXT`, or variables etc, the query should be as simple as possible.

Comment: Although `^` is special, it isn't special if it doesn't form a valid pattern -- `LIKE '%[^]%'` works without any escape override. This works when combined with other characters as well, as long as care is taken that `^` is not at the start so no valid range pattern is formed. The same applies to `-` as long as it's not in the middle. `]` is the only character that definitely needs escaping when combined with others, since there is no way to include it otherwise. So `'%[^ !"#$%&''()*+,./0-9A-Za-z:;<=>@[\]-^]%' ESCAPE '\'` works as well.

Comment: Oh, add ``\\``, `_`, `{`, `}` and `~` as necessary. Again, `_` isn't special within a pattern and hence needs no escaping, while ``\\`` is special only because we've picked it as the escape character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't escape it.**

As you already found out, if you want to find the caret, i.e. you are interested in it as a character, you have to escape it.

```
WHERE SampleString LIKE '%[\^]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

When you are trying to find strings that do not contain something, i.e. use the caret for its "function", you have to **not** escape it:

```
where SampleString LIKE '%[^~{}]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

You could actually use both escaping and not escaping in the following example, where you would get strings that contains something else other than the caret:

```
where SampleString LIKE '%[^\^]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: Turns out the issue was not with the caret, but with something else in my query. I had managed to get to the `'%[^\^]%'` part, but thought my query was wrong, oops. Coming back after lunch to look at the code again is the true solution. Lol!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the question mark; the query itself with the special characters is alright.

```
select * from SpecialCharacter WHERE SampleString LIKE '%[^ !"#$\%&''()*+,-./0-9A-Za-z:;<=>@?\[\\\]\_\^{}~]%' ESCAPE '\'
```